Stuck creating Dpkg files with Dist::Zilla
Any Perl gurus out there? I'm trying to package up my CPAN module for Ubuntu/Debian and I'm just getting started with Dist::Zilla's plugin to create a .deb package, but I get errors in the build stage. I'm looking for the form of the template files that Dist::Zilla will work on to produce the files that dpkg will need and I don't know enough about the Ubuntu ecosystem to work it out.
My dist.ini file has nothing in the [Dpkg] section and the relevant output is
...
[Dpkg] Used default for file 'compat'
[Dpkg] Added file for 'compat'
[Dpkg] Used default for file 'control'
[Dpkg] Added file for 'control'
[Dpkg] No template or default for 'default'
No template or default provided for 'default' at /usr/local/share/perl5/5.36/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/Dpkg.pm line 301.

so it has sensible defaults for the compat and control files, but fails because I just don't have templates for the default, install, postinst and postrm files.
There are no dist.ini files that I can steal from CPAN that use this plugin.

Looks like I should be using dh-dist-zilla as it's had more recent development. There are some talks at noone.org but you probably want the one on packaging
